# Will a Modem -> Switch -> Access Point setup work?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, modem, wireless-access-point, switch

So, I'm planning on chucking out my ISP's router because it's just plain not good enough.  I'm planning on moving to a `Modem -> Switch -> Access Point` setup.

I plan to have a DrayTek Vigor 130 Modem (ADSL2+/VDSL) which will work with my BT Infinity service.

I will plug the **(WAN?)** port on the back into a NETGEAR GS116UK 16-Port Gigabit Unmanaged Switch. **(on any port?)**

I will then plug Ubiquiti Networks UniFi AC AP into the switch.

This is all the equipment I will have for the network (except for clients, obviously...)

I have a few questions though...

1)  Will this actually work?

2)  How will IP addresses be assigned?  Will it be via DHCP from the modem?  My switch is unmanaged, so...

3)  Is the port (not the DSL port) on the back of the modem that plugs into the switch the WAN port?

4)  Can I plug that into any port on the switch, or do I need to plug it into a specific port?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just replace the BT modem/router with a simple modem. You need a router behind it.
The rest of your setup will then work.

See - http://www.draytek.co.uk/products/business/vigor-130

- Bridge (pass) a single IP address or a whole public subnet
- Ideal Partner device for DrayTek dual-WAN products
  or any other vendor's Ethernet WAN firewall
- Ethernet Connection for client device (router, PC etc.)

You can connect any device to the Vigor 130 which has a PPPoE client facility, which includes PCs, most Ethernet-WAN routers and the Apple Airport/Time Capsule™ products.

[image]

Comment: The modem you linked is the same as what I wrote...  Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you forgot to read the info, or look at the picture. Answer updated.

Comment: Oh...  Sorry.  Does that mean that the modem takes the connection, then the router is what assigns IPs, does port forwarding, etc?

Comment: Why buy the modem-only portion when you'll need a router on the other end (yes, you could use any old Ethernet-WAn based router but if it's old it'll be slow)... when Draytek offer an all-in-one that also has built-in wifi and can be VLANed...? http://www.draytek.co.uk/products/business/vigor-2860 approx £240... The 130 is £80 + you'll have to buy a ethernet-WAN based router to compliment the modem.

Comment: Yup, the modem pretty much just modulates/demodulates the signal & carries such as PPoE to negotiate the connection. The router does all the important stuff behind that, usually inc DNS, DHCP Firewall etc

Comment: I would be wary of going too far along the 'corporate' hardware route though - the further you get from 'consumer' devices, the harder they are to set up & administer.